# Advice on all getters of a given package not firing

Tags: java, spring, maven, aop, spring-aop

I am working with neo4j and in order to implement a JPA style lazy-loading, I came across a solution that uses aspect to pre-fetch full objects from neo4j when getters of the domain model are called.

In an attempt to implement this solution I have built a small Maven project with a minimalistic domain model and an aspect that should fire when getters are called:

```
https://github.com/samuel-kerrien/neo4j-aspect-auto-fetching
```

For some reasons the Aspect is initialising but the advice doesn't seem to get executed. To reproduce the issue, just run the following JUnit test:

```
playground.neo4j.domain.UserTest
```

Having not worked extensively with aspects before, I am suspecting I may have poorly configured the project in Maven. My intention was to get a load time weaving but the only way I could start up my tests has been to configure surefire so that spring-instrument is being loaded as an agent.

Comment: Do you have more experience with Neo4j? Because this can get really nasty when getting exceptions during the usage of an managed object. Write locks would kill this fetching. I've done some anaylsis 1.5 years ago and at that point every write operation created a lock (including related entities). But maybe i missed something.

Comment: Not sure about write locks, the doc (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-locking.html) says it only kicks in when changing the model while I am only trying to read data back.  In this question I'd just like to focus on getting the aspect part to work so I can then do some benchmarking. Cheers !